# Passing values between views gives (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, segue

I'm trying to pass some values from a view to another, but the values are always (null). Here my code.

First:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Thanks" sender:self];
```

Then:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    ThanksViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    [vc set_event_image_url:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bla bla bla %@.png", event_id]];
    [vc set_event_name:eventTitle];        
}
```

In the receiver I'm initiating the variables.

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString* _event_name;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString* _event_image_url;
```

AND

```
@synthesize _event_image_url;
@synthesize _event_name;
```

The values are now (null). Any Ideas why it fails? The segue is added to the storyboard too.

Comment: How you are connecting the segue ?

Comment: A modal segue in the Storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the underscores from your property names - it's not the standard way of naming things in objective-c and it's just possible that it could be confusing things (cocoa by default will synthesise you instance variables that begin with an underscore).

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString* eventName;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString* eventImageUrl;
```

You can also remove your synthesize statements - objective-c will do your synthesizing for you, so they're not necessary.

You would then call `[vc setEventTitle:blah];`

However, the main issue is that you've implemented `prepareForSegue` incorrectly! The proper method signature should be:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;
```

Add the sender parameter and you should find it'll be called.

Comment: I've changed the code, but it still doesn't work. I think I've traced the bug to prepareForSegue not being run. Why is still a mystery.

Comment: Ah - you've got the method signature wrong! It needs a `sender` parameter. I've updated my answer.

Comment: There it was! Thank you very much, James.

Comment: I wouldn't have noticed if you hadn't mentioned it not being run. Teamwork! :)

Comment: Yeah, we are awesome, James :D